# Options to parse array in JS + Jquery present in an external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I read some of the topics related to parsing an external array and I can't find the way to retrieve directly the array present on another JS file.

Basically it would be to **load an array located in list1.js in main.js**

For example, let's say I'd like to have this loaded on my main.js :

```
          var arr =
          [
{
    "Numéro": "1",
    "Chinois": "爱",
    "Pinyin": "ài",
    "Français": "aimer, affection, apprécier",
    "Classificateurs": ""
},
{
    "Numéro": "2",
    "Chinois": "八",
    "Pinyin": "bā",
    "Français": "huit, 8",
    "Classificateurs": ""
},
{
    "Numéro": "3",
    "Chinois": "爸爸",
    "Pinyin": "bà ba",
    "Français": "père, papa",
    "Classificateurs": "CL: 个,位[wèi]"
},
{
    "Numéro": "4",
    "Chinois": "杯子",
    "Pinyin": "bēi zi",
    "Français": "verre, coupe",
    "Classificateurs": "CL:个,支[zhī],枝[zhī]"
},
{
    "Numéro": "5",
    "Chinois": "北京",
    "Pinyin": "Běi jīng",
    "Français": "Pékin, Beijing",
    "Classificateurs": ""
},
{
    "Numéro": "6",
    "Chinois": "本",
    "Pinyin": "běn",
    "Français": "origine, racine, effectivement, ",
    "Classificateurs": "CL pour livres ou périodiques"
},
{
    "Numéro": "7",
    "Chinois": "不",
    "Pinyin": "bù",
    "Français": "(préfixe) négation",
    "Classificateurs": ""
}];
```

This var arr is located at the beginning of my list1.js. This file is composed of a large array. I build several a list and I would like to retrieve them one by one (since they are large arrays - 2000+ items- , putting them all in my main.js would make more readable.

What would be the best option to parse this kind of data (I read about Json / Ajax) and what would be the most lightweight/fast solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd have to say getting that with AJAX and parsing it to JSON would be the lightest/fastest solution.

Comment: Why do you think you would need to parse that? Just execute it as a script.

Comment: How would I execute the script to retrieve that array in my main javascript file ?

Comment: Just include the script before your main script, then access `arr` from there.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, i didn't think i was that easy.